# Strange viewbox font sizing behaviour inside Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, requestanimationframe, viewport-units

https://jsfiddle.net/diegojsrw/od12s9b4/14/

```
c.font = "100vh sans-serif";
c.fillStyle = "white";
c.fillText(fps.toFixed(0), w/2, 0);
```

Initially, the text's height seems fine.

However, when I resize the window, the text doesn't resize together. The text is constantly drawn on canvas (using `requestAnimationFrame`).

The text size is only re-adjusted when I switch to another tab then switch back to this tab.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

#### You are facing a webkit bug. Both latests Chrome and Safari are concerned.

In the Canvas2D API, relative units/values should get computed at setting and this computed value will get saved and used.

This means that your relative `100vw` value will get computed to its corresponding value in absolute `px` unit.

This is one of the reasons it is advised to always use absolute units from the canvas API (among others like tweaks in roundings etc.).

But if you really want to use this unit, then you have to set it everytime it has changed, so you could go blindly and inside your loop just set `ctx.font` again before calling `fillText()`, but for performances, I would advise you use a *dirty flag*, that would get raised in the window's `resize` event, and only update the `ctx.font` property when this flag is raised.

#### But this is only fine for browsers that do follow the specs...

I have no real clue as to when webkit browsers will compute this value, as even resetting the `font` property to something else won't do, and even setting it to an other value (e.g switching between 20vh and 21vh)  won't do either...

So the only workaround I can see for now, is to actually compute yourself this value. For viewport size, that's not so hard (`innerWidth / (100 / vw_val)`), but even for other relative units, you can actually set this fontSize on the canvas directly and call `getComputedStyle()` on the canvas.

```js
let dirtySize = true; // this is our resize flag
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let fontStyle = ' Arial, sans-serif';

anim(0);
// the animation loop
function anim(time) {
  // call the drawing methods
  draw(Math.round(time/1e2));
  // lwoer the flags
  dirtySize = false;
  // do it again next frame
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

function draw(txt) {
  // clear
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // only if needed
  if(dirtySize) {
    // get the cpmputed style from our DOM element
    const fontSize = getComputedStyle(canvas).fontSize;
    // or could be 
    // const fontSize = (innerWidth / (100 / 20)) + 'px';

    ctx.font = fontSize + fontStyle;
  }
  // draw everytime
  ctx.fillText(txt, 0, 100);
}
// on window's resize event
window.addEventListener('resize',
  evt => dirtySize = true, // raise our flag
  { passive: true }
);
```

```css
#canvas {
  font-size: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The `font` property is always set inside the drawing loop, before the text is drawn on canvas. That alone doesn't update the actual size. It can be checked at the three lines of code above.

Comment: @DiegoS. Oh I see now, sorry I misread your question and answered the general case. Now I see that it is actually a webkit bug (Both in Chrome and Safari), and since I was on FF I didn't noticed it... Will edit.